# replace special values for each column of a data frame

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

If i want to replace all the negative values as well as values of (999,9991,9992,9996) for all the columns of my data frame with -100, how should i do it. I want to save it as a new data frame and not on the same data frame. 
in my data set i have hundreds of columns

```
x<-c(-1,-2,0,1,9991)
y<-c(1,2,3,4,999)
z<-c(100,101,-999,9992,9996)
data<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read up on how to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and edit your question. Users here will want to critique existing code.

Comment: Please show code that you have tried to achieve this solution that is not working so users can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `lapply` to replace values in each column.

```
data2 <- data

data2[] <- lapply(data2, function(x){
  x[x < 0 | x %in% c(999, 9991, 9992, 9996)] <- -100
  return(x)
})
data2
#      x    y    z
# 1 -100    1  100
# 2 -100    2  101
# 3    0    3 -100
# 4    1    4 -100
# 5 -100 -100 -100
```

Comment: if I want to replace these special values with the mean of that variable what shall i do? i tried the following but doesnt work

  data[] <- lapply(data, function(x){
  x[x < 0 | x %in% c(999, 9991, 9992, 9996)] <- NA
  return(x)
})

data[] <- lapply(data, function(x){
  x[is.na(x)]<- mean(x)
  return(x)
})

Comment: Please search for relevant questions. If no one asked a similar question before, you may want to begin a new post with this new question.